# How to check distance between locations seperated by sea

Tags: javascript, google-distancematrix-api

I've been using the [Google Matrix Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en) to check the distance between two locations. I'm running into a problem, however, whenever I try to make a query between two locations that are seperated by water.

For example, the following query that tries to find the distance between New York and Honolulu (seperated by water):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=New%20York%20City&destinations=Honolulu&language=en-EN&key=AIzaFAKEFnUaaPx0PpeFAKEKEYxx6glRArKEYBO0
```

but it returns **ZERO_RESULTS:**

```
{
    destination_addresses: [
        "Honolulu, HI, USA"
    ],
    origin_addresses: [
        "New York, NY, USA"
    ],
    rows: [{
        elements: [{
            status: "ZERO_RESULTS"
        }]
    }],
    status: "OK"
}
```

Are there any other `free` APIs that can find the distance between two locations, regardless of water? Or is there a way to find the distance with the [Google Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en) regardless of water?

Comment: What kind of distance do you need? If you need a straight line you can do it yourself with a simple function that takes the Xs and the Ys. If you need to calculate the path that the plane or the ferry takes that's another parameter to add to your query.

Comment: @CHAMMEMRaed A rough straight line. That said, the two locations are coming from an input box, which doesn't have Lat Long

Comment: You can search using some API (Google Places/Foursquare/Etc..) and determine the lat/lang.